# Joomla Pagination on click error "Joomla is not defined" only on frontend

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, joomla-component

i've a problem with a component i'm making.

I'm using "Joomla! 3.4.1 Stable".

The Joomla javascript object is not loading in front-end and so when i click on pagination it gives me error and load the index page. The same page, but in the admin side, works perfectly.

Here is the page:

http://www.pesceinrete.com/php/index.php?option=com_pesceinrete&view=listpe

I've tried to change the live_site variable in the configuration file of joomla and also to put these lines of code in the view.html.php file of the view but it seems nothing changes.

```
JHtml::_('behavior.core');
JHtml::_('behavior.framework');
```

I can't see the Joomla javascript object loading in the other pages too. I'm new to Joomla, and all these different versions (2.0, 2.5, 3.0) are confusing me. Someone says to use "HtmlBehavior::core();" but it gives me an error (function doesn't exist).

Please help me, i'm going crazy, thank you all in advance.

PS: The site use "K2" plugin, but i'm using standard Joomla pagination so i don't know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit late answer but still could be useful for others.

As stated [here](https://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Using_JPagination_in_your_component#Implementing_Pagination_in_Front_End) you need to add `JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');` to your template to load `Joomla` class.